# No view is being rendered in re-frame app

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, re-frame

Here's a simple re-frame app that I tried to create based on the existing example project in re-frame's github repo. But it is only displaying things from the html file. Seems like no event is being dispatched. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
(ns simple.core
  (:require [reagent.core :as reagent]
            [re-frame.core :as rf]
            [clojure.string :as str]))

(rf/reg-event-db
  :rand
  (fn [db [_ _]]
    (assoc db :winner ( + 2 (rand-int 3)))))

(rf/reg-sub
  :winner
  (fn [db _]
    (:winner db)))

(def participants ["Alice" "Bob" "Ellie"])

(defn winners-name
  [idx]
  (get participants idx))

(defn show-winner 
  []
  [:h1
   (winners-name
    (@(rf/subscribe [:winner])))])

(defn ui
  []
  [:div
   [:h1 "Lottery"]
   [show-winner]])

(defn ^:export run
  []
  (rf/dispatch-sync [:rand])
  (reagent/render [ui]
                  (js/document.getElementById "app")))
```

Comment: What version of re-frame are you using? There was a bug introduced in the most recent .0 release and was fixed shortly after.

Comment: I'm using the latest one. The problem is fixed, I had an extra pair of parenthesis which was causing the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused because of a pair of extra parenthesis around the `deref` thing. So the function `winners-name` is treating it as a list instead of an integer.

```
(winners-name
  (@(rf/subscribe [:winner]))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:rand` handler will produce nil most times since you are adding 2 to the generated value and the `participants` vector only has 3 entries.

Comment: Thanks for finding out the bug! It was introduces while refactoring. I fixed that but still no difference.